# How do I find the smallest element of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, element, minimum

Here is how I tried:

```cpp
int main ()
{
    // example array
    int x [] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };

    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    int min = 0;
    int index;

    int i;
    for ( i=1; i < size; i++)
    {
      if (x [i]< 2)
      {
        index = i ;
        min = x [i];
      }
    }
    cout << index << " " << min << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement?

Is there a more general way of finding the minimum (that is: without specifically using the obvious minimum of the given array, as I did with `x [i] < 2`)?

Comment: [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) springs to mind.

Comment: I think it does not find the smallest element. It finds the last element which is smaller than 2. And you will get undefined behavior if there is none.

Comment: if you want to implement it yourself `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is a good initial guess for the minimum value

Comment: @RichardCritten sorting the list first is O(n*logn). A linear search is O(n)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: I'd update the code to ensure size is greater than zero.  Aside from that, initialize min to be the first element, and then loop the remaining items.

Comment: Does your code work with `int x [] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 12 };`?

Comment: Starting with `INT_MAX` is unnecessary. Start with the first element.

Comment: not if you want to define this function as a function outside of the main, as you will not have to check arrays bound. Think about what happens if size is 0.

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing your `index` variable, and you are initializing your `min` variable to 0 instead of the value of the 1st element (since you start the loop at the 2nd element), and you are ignoring the current `min` inside the loop's comparison.

Change your code to be more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    // example array
    int x[] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };

    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    int min = x[0];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (x[i] < min)
        {
            index = i;
            min = x[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << index << " " << min << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you should use the standard [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) algorithm instead, which handles this for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    // example array
    int x[] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };
    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    // or: auto size = std::size(x);

    int* min = std::min_element(x, x + size);
    // or: auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(x), std::end(x));

    int index = min - x;
    // or: auto index = std::distance(x, min);

    std::cout << index << " " << *min << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this one, if for no other reason than initializing `min` with `x[0]`. For a given container, there's no reason to "go global."

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use your function instead of `std::min_element`:

```cpp
#include <climits> // for INT_MAX define

int main ()
{
// example array
    int x [] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };

    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    int min = INT_MAX; // you have to set your value at the highest possible value of INT32
    int index = -1;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (x [i]< min)
        {
            index = i ;
            min = x [i];
        }
    }
    cout << index << " " << min << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not find the minimum in the array. It only finds the last element that is smaller than `2`.

You need to compare the elements with `min` not with some static value. A good initial guess for `min` is either `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` or the value of the first element.

You start the loop at `i=1`, ie you skip the first element, thats fine if you use `x[0]` as initial value for `min`. Also you forgot to initialize `index` which is bad, because if the loop does not find an element smaller than `2` printing `index` later invokes undefined behavior.

The following assumes that the array is not empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main () {
    // example array
    int x [] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };

    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    //int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int min = x[0];
    int index = 0;

    for (size_t i=1; i < size; i++) {
        if (x [i]< min) {
            index = i ;
            min = x[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << index << " " << min << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, the idiomatic way would be to use `std::min_element` which returns an iterator to the minimum element.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more general way of finding the minimum?

Since you asked, **yes**.  There is a more general way.

[`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) solves this very problem.

```
int main ()
{
    // example array
    int x [] { 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 12 };

    auto iterator = std::min_element( std::begin(x), std::end(x) );

    auto index = std::distance(std::begin(x), iterator);
    auto min = *iterator;
    cout << index << " " << min << endl;
}
```

[(See it live)](https://www.godbolt.org/z/6d9eWz)

Comment: `const auto index = std::distance(std::begin(x), iterator);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed!  (I'll leave `const` out so as not to distract from the spirit of the question)